# exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'Friends' was not found in the registry; used paths:

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

Hi Im using Socialengine 4.5 and I'm getting the following error. Can someone help me determine the reason, based on the error message and the stack trace?

Error:

```
Error Code: 8094cd
exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'Friends' was not found in the registry; used paths:
Messages_View_Helper_: /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/Messages/views/helpers/
User_View_Helper_: /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/User/View/Helper/
Seaocore_View_Helper_: /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/Seaocore/View/Helper/
Advancedmembers_View_Helper_: /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/Advancedmembers/View/Helper/
Activity_View_Helper_: /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/Activity/View/Helper/
Core_View_Helper_: /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/Core/View/Helper/
Engine_View_Helper_: Engine/View/Helper/
Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/Album/views/helpers/:/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/Core/views/helpers/' in /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:406
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/View/Abstract.php(1120): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('Friends')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/View/Abstract.php(569): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'friends')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/View/Abstract.php(336): Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('friends')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/Core/views/scripts/_composeTag.tpl(31): Zend_View_Abstract->__call('friends', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/Core/views/scripts/_composeTag.tpl(31): Zend_View->friends()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/View.php(108): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/View/Abstract.php(835): Zend_View->_run('/var/www/vhosts...')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/View/Helper/Partial.php(103): Zend_View_Abstract->render('_composeTag.tpl')
#8 [internal function]: Zend_View_Helper_Partial->partial('_composeTag.tpl', 'core')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/View/Abstract.php(342): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/Messages/views/scripts/messages/compose.tpl(201): Zend_View_Abstract->__call('partial', Array)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/Messages/views/scripts/messages/compose.tpl(201): Zend_View->partial('_composeTag.tpl', 'core')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/View.php(108): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#13 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/View/Abstract.php(835): Zend_View->_run('/var/www/vhosts...')
#14 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(903): Zend_View_Abstract->render('messages/compos...')
#15 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(924):



Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('messages/compos...', NULL)
#16 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(963): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(277): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch()
#18 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action.php(523): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch()
#19 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('composeAction')
#20 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#21 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(75): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#22 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(160): Core_Bootstrap->run()
#23 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/application/index.php(205): Engine_Application->run()
#24 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/index.php(24): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#25 {main}`
```

As Kirk Hammett say the problem have to be on the ComposeTag.tlp code Please can someone tell me what to do:

```
<?php
/**
 * SocialEngine
 *
 * @category   Application_Core
 * @package    Core
 * @copyright  Copyright 2006-2010 Webligo Developments
 * @license    http://www.socialengine.com/license/
 * @version    $Id: _composeTag.tpl 9900 2013-02-14 02:20:25Z shaun $
 * @author     John
 */
?>

<?php $this->headScript()
    ->appendFile($this->layout()->staticBaseUrl . 'externals/autocompleter/Observer.js')
    ->appendFile($this->layout()->staticBaseUrl . 'externals/autocompleter/Autocompleter.js')
    ->appendFile($this->layout()->staticBaseUrl . 'externals/autocompleter/Autocompleter.Local.js')
    ->appendFile($this->layout()->staticBaseUrl . 'externals/autocompleter/Autocompleter.Request.js')
    ->appendFile($this->layout()->staticBaseUrl . 'application/modules/Core/externals/scripts/composer_tag.js') ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  en4.core.runonce.add(function() {
    composeInstance.addPlugin(new Composer.Plugin.Tag({
      suggestOptions : {
        'url' : '<?php echo $this->url(array(), 'default', true) . '/user/friends/suggest' ?>',
        'data' : {
          'format' : 'json'
        }
      },
      'suggestProto' : 'local',
      'suggestParam' : <?php echo Zend_Json::encode($this->friends()) ?>
    }));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you actually have a view helper called "Friends"? It's paid software, I'm sure you can ask them to help

Comment: Hi Ashley thanks for your answer, i check and i didnt find Friends plugin. About to ask them my license support is expired ;( so they want to charge me 50$ just for that, Please help me!!!! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTTION:

CHANGE :

```
'suggestParam' : <?php echo Zend_Json::encode($this->friends()) ?>
```

FOR:

```
'suggestParam' : <?php echo $this->action('suggest', 'friends', 'user', array('sendNow' => false, 'includeSelf' => true)) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack trace says that you have wrong call of function friends() in a view:

```
httpdocs/application/modules/Core/views/scripts/_composeTag.tpl
```

probably it looks like

```
$this->friends()
```

or something like that. That's where you should continue to search the reason of this issue.

Comment: Hi Kirk Thanks for your answer. can i show you the code of my composetag.tpl? To see where is the problem im really bad ;(

Comment: Well, looks like I was wrong and it's ok with the code you've placed. The problem is you can't access helper or plugin 'Friends' to use view helper like this: `$this->friends()`. It's hard to say why, sorry.